# List returned by Entity Framework is null

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have these two classes, `Field` and `Field2` with a one-to-many relationship.

When I am trying to get `Field`, the list returns with records with the id and the name, which is correct. But trying to read the `Field2` from `Field` is always empty.

What can be the cause? I have tried everything. I can see the FK in the database etc.

```
public class Field : IEntityBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Field")]
    public virtual ICollection<Field2> Field2 { get; set; }
}

public class Field2: IEntityBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int FieldId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(FieldId))]
    public virtual Field Field { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: how do you fetch this from EF? do you call `.Include()` method?

Comment: i have a generic repository so it does await _context.Set<T>().ToListAsync(); but i heard that virtual does the same thing as include

Comment: It was in previous versions of EF. Now you need to `Include` explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the Include() method. See the example below,

```cs
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
    var list = context.Field
        .Include(f => f.Field2)    
        .ToList();    

    foreach (var field in list)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Field Name: {0}", field.Name);
        foreach (var field2 in field.Field2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\tField 2 ID: {0}", field.Id);
        }
    }
}
```

[Entity framework Include](https://entityframework.net/when-to-use-include)

Comment: i am using a generic repository so i dont think i can do this

Comment: Yes do-able. Check this example here https://entityframework.net/knowledge-base/26590034/-include--lambda-in-generic-repository. So you will need to modify the Repo as shown here

Comment: @Tahtoh, _i am using a generic repository_ - this is first reason not to use generic repository ;)

Comment: @Tahtoh given generic parameter T, introduce a generic repository method that returns to you an `IQueryable<T>`, `GetAsQueryable()` for example. Then you will be able to say `repo.GetAsQueryable().Include(x => x.NavigationProperty)...`

Answer (score 2):

Include can do it. As you use generic repository after I read your comments, you can replace your generic Get() function with this.

```
var list = db.Set<T>();
var key = db.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(T)).FindPrimaryKey().Properties.FirstOrDefault();
    var foreignkeys = key.GetContainingPrimaryKey().GetReferencingForeignKeys();

    if (foreignkeys.Count() > 0)
    {
        foreach (var item in foreignkeys)
            list = list.Include<T>(item.DeclaringEntityType.DisplayName());
    }
return list;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use below code in your repository to include navigation properties for your `_context.Set<T>`:

```
var query = _context.Set<T>().AsQueryable();

foreach (var property in _context.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(T)).GetNavigations())
            query = query.Include(property.Name);

return await query.ToListAsync();
```

Refer to [Include all navigation properties using Reflection in generic repository using EF Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44682555/include-all-navigation-properties-using-reflection-in-generic-repository-using-e)

Comment: Does this do it recursivly for all the inside types of the main object? @Xing Zou

Comment: @tatoh it searches for all navigation properties of the main project

Answer (score 0):

**It is about the ORM (Object-relational mapping) pattern you use.**

This patterns are the ways how you want to load related entities; *eager*, *load*, ...

You can reach related entity by (most common way) **Include()** or you can choose any other pattern according to your project. Please take a look at [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data)