# Programmatically obtain metadata about indexes and constraints from Entity Framework 6's object context

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first

I'm working with unique indexes in a code-first environment. They are defined like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>().HasIndex(foo => foo.Bar).IsUnique()
```

Using Entity Framework's metadata model, I would like to programmatically get a list of indexes (or constraints) given a specified type (`Foo` in this case).

Doing similar things with EF have proven to be relatively easy. For example, you can get a list of property names that are the primary key of a specified set, like so:
[Entity Framework code first. Find primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7253943/entity-framework-code-first-find-primary-key). Entity Framework also convieniently exposes navigation properties through similar methods: [EF5 How to get list of navigation properties for a domain object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17886725/ef5-how-to-get-list-of-navigation-properties-for-a-domain-object).

Is there something similar available for (unique) indexes?

---

**EDIT:** Example `DbContext`:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Index]
    public int SomeNumber { get; set; }
}

public class FooContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Foo> Foos { get; set; }

    public FooContext() : base("DefaultConnection") { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Using this `DbContext`, @Kahbazi's method of obtaining the `PropertyIndexes` doesn't work, it will be an empty collection.

When I use the fluent API instead of an explicit `DbSet`, with the following code:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>().HasIndex(foo => foo.SomeNumber);
```

... then `"Configuration"` (see @Kahbazi's answer) will disappear from the `MetadataProperties`, resulting in System.InvalidOperationException: 'Sequence contains no matching element'

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code to get the indexes

```
Context context = new Context();
IObjectContextAdapter objectContextAdapter = (IObjectContextAdapter)context;

object configuration = objectContextAdapter.ObjectContext.CreateObjectSet<Foo>()
    .EntitySet
    .MetadataProperties
    .Where(x => x.Name == "Configuration")
    .First()
    .Value;

var propertyIndexes = configuration.GetType().GetProperty("PropertyIndexes", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(configuration);
var list = (System.Collections.IEnumerable)propertyIndexes;
foreach (var item in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

But since most of the classes are internal, you have to  use Reflection

Comment: I tried this in EF6 but there's no "Configuration" metadata property in the collection, am I missing something?

Comment: Can you post your dbcontext and entity so I can check it out

Comment: I awarded you the bounty because it was about to expire, but I actually haven't gotten this to work yet. I've edited my question to include an example DbContext.

Comment: @Rudey It's weird the code works for me. which version on Entityframework you are using?

Comment: I'm currently using the latest version of EF6

Comment: ditto regarding this not working with ef6